How and why use call_once()?
From N3220, §7.28.2.1 “The call_once function”:

Synopsis
#include <threads.h>
void call_once(once_flag *flag, void (*func)(void));

Description
The call_once function uses the
once_flag pointed to by flag to ensure that func is called exactly
once, the first time the call_once function is called with that value
of flag. Completion of an effective call to the call_once function
synchronizes with all subsequent calls to the call_once function with
the same value of flag.
Returns
The call_once function returns no value.

From what it sounds like, is this supposed to be used for init()/config() functions that are only supposed to be called once? Or am I completely misunderstanding it and it is something pertinent to threads?
What is this useful for? What is flag, and how is it relevant here?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once shows usage example

@KamilCuk "The completion of the function func synchronizes with all previous or subsequent calls to call_once with the same flag variable." <== What does this mean?

Which part is unclear to you?

@KamilCuk Well, everything after "function func". I am not very familiar with threads. :(

@Closevoter 1) How in the world am I seeking recommendations for software tools and libraries? I am asking about the usage of a function. Questions asking about scanf() and printf() don't get closed for seeking recommendations for software tools. 2. I do not see any duplicate about call_once().

Let's assume the following:

The same function is provided for all calls with a given flag object.
The same flag object is provided for all calls with a given function.
The function is only called via call_once.

If those assumptions are met, the following two guarantees are made for any function provided as an argument:

The function will be called only once.
call_once will only return once the function has returned.

The second guarantee means that other threads will block until the provided function returns if it's currently executing.
This is useful for initializing/populating shared variables.
